# Sql Server OLEDB provider error. The provider ran out of memory error

Tags: sql-server, oledb

Sorry for my english :). 
I have a windows service. Service report some excel files weekly. But ı got a"OLE DB provider 'SQLOLEDB' reported an error. The provider ran out of memory" Ole Db error. Service use SQl Server 8.00.194 and it link another SQL Server. I do not know why ı receive this error. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using base SQL Server 2000 RTM (8.00.194) then at least apply latest service packs. This also applies to the client too (in case I misunderstood the question) because MDAC etc is updated